# Is it worked Nashorn JS object to java.util.Map?

Tags: java-8, nashorn

I have java method

```
void someMethod(String str, Map map) {
    ...
}
```

From JS call this method

```
var map = new Object()
map.key1 = "val1"
...someMethod(str, map)
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: None of the fixed arity signatures
[(java.lang.String, java.util.Map)] of method org.prjctor.shell.Bash.eval
match the argument types [java.lang.String, jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.JO]
```

But in Nashorn docs "Mapping of Data Types Between Java and JavaScript" said "Every JavaScript object is also a java.util.Map so APIs receiving maps will receive them directly".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well, the way I would read the docs, I would say that there is nothing that you are doing wrong. The statement you quote ("Every JavaScript object is also a java.util.Map") appears to be plain wrong as one can see from the inheritance structure of the class JO:
jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.JO 
 extends jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptObject (implements jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.PropertyAccess)
 extends jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.PropertyListenerManager (implements jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.PropertyListener)
 extends java.lang.Object

Answer (score 2):

Agree with the previous answers that you cannot do this as the docs have implied.
However you could create and pass a map as follows

```
..
var HashMap = Java.type('java.util.HashMap');
var map = new HashMap();
map.put('1', 'val1');
...someMethod(str, map)
```

Comment: or "java.util.ArrayList" for Arrays.

Answer (score 0):

The [doc](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/prog_guide/javascript.html#A1147390) says ""Every JavaScript object implements the java.util.Map interface". But this sample test program shows thats not the case.

```
public final class NashornTestMap {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
        ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine nashorn = factory.getEngineByName("nashorn");
        nashorn.eval(""
                +"load(\"nashorn:mozilla_compat.js\");"
                + "importClass(Packages.NashornTestMap);"
                + "var map={};"
                + "map[\"Key\"]=String(\"Val\"); "
                + "var test = new NashornTestMap();"
                + "test.test(map);"
                + "");
    }

    public void test(Map<String, String> obj){
        System.out.println(obj);
    }       
}
```

The above code give exception "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.JO4 to java.util.Map". This [link](http://marc.info/?l=openjdk-nashorn-dev&m=138016915730891) confirms this.

However you can use Map inside your script and call the java objects directly, like this.

```
public final class NashornTestMap {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
        ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine nashorn = factory.getEngineByName("nashorn");
        nashorn.eval(""
                +"load(\"nashorn:mozilla_compat.js\");"
                + "importClass(Packages.NashornTestMap);"
                + "var HashMap = Java.type(\"java.util.HashMap\");"             
                + "var map = new HashMap();"
                + "map.put(0, \"value1\");"
                + "var test = new NashornTestMap();"
                + "test.test(map);"
                + "");
    }

    public void test(Map<String, String> obj){
        System.out.println(obj);
    }       

}
```

Returns  "{0=value1}"