# Nashorn ScriptObjectMirror JS -> Java type conversion

Tags: java, java-8, nashorn, scriptengine

When I access a JavaScript object's member variable using Nashorn ScriptObjectMirror.get(), the returned object's type seems to be determined at runtime. For example, if the value fits in a Java int, get() seems to return a Java Integer. If the value won't fit in an int, get() seems to return a Java Long, and so on.

Right now, I use instanceof to check the type and convert the value to a long.

Is there a more convenient way of getting a member's value without loss and without checking the type in Java? Perhaps Nashorn could always give me a Java Double, throwing an error in case the member's not numeric.

I can imagine this is a rather narrow case that probably shouldn't be handled by Nashorn...

Example:

```
package com.tangotangolima.test.nashorn_types;

import jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.ScriptObjectMirror;

import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptException;
import java.io.StringReader;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ScriptException {
        final ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
        final ScriptEngine js = mgr.getEngineByName("nashorn");

        final String script = "" +
                "var p = 1;" +
                "var q = " + (Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1L) + ";" +
                "var r = {" +
                "s: 1," +
                "t: " + (Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1L) +
                " };";

        js.eval(new StringReader(script));

        say(js.get("p").getClass().getName());      // -> java.lang.Integer
        say(js.get("q").getClass().getName());      // -> java.lang.Long

        final ScriptObjectMirror r = (ScriptObjectMirror) js.get("r");

        say(r.get("s").getClass().getName());       // -> java.lang.Integer
        say(r.get("t").getClass().getName());       // -> java.lang.Long
    }

    static void say(String s) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recommended approach is to check "instanceof java.lang.Number" from java code -- if you expect JavaScript "number" value. Once casted to Number, you can convert to int, long, double by calling methods such as intValue, longValue etc.

Answer (score 13):

This code can do ScriptObjectMirror JS -> Java conversion

```
private static Object convertIntoJavaObject(Object scriptObj) {
    if (scriptObj instanceof ScriptObjectMirror) {
        ScriptObjectMirror scriptObjectMirror = (ScriptObjectMirror) scriptObj;
        if (scriptObjectMirror.isArray()) {
            List<Object> list = Lists.newArrayList();
            for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : scriptObjectMirror.entrySet()) {
                list.add(convertIntoJavaObject(entry.getValue()));
            }
            return list;
        } else {
            Map<String, Object> map = Maps.newHashMap();
            for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : scriptObjectMirror.entrySet()) {
                map.put(entry.getKey(), convertIntoJavaObject(entry.getValue()));
            }
            return map;
        }
    } else {
        return scriptObj;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws ScriptException, NoSuchMethodException {
    final ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");
    engine.eval("function objProvider(){return {a:1, b:'2','c': true,'d': {'e':[],'f':['1',{'g':45}]}};}");
    final Object scriptObj = ((Invocable) engine).invokeFunction("objProvider");

    Object javaObj = convertIntoJavaObject(scriptObj);
    System.out.println(javaObj);
    //{a=1, b=2, c=true, d={e=[], f=[1, {g=45}]}}
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20512621/is-it-worked-nashorn-js-object-to-java-util-map

Comment: This answer unfortunately does not work because it cannot be casted... See above link for more information; can construct Java collections straight within JS though.

Answer (score 2):

I really like [Igor's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1306536/igor) approach. Here is his `convertToJavaObject()` code as a complete program using only standard Java and in addition to including a `toJava()` also includes a `toJavascript()` that goes the other way.

```
import jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.ScriptObjectMirror;

import javax.script.Invocable;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {

  @SuppressWarnings("removal")
  private static Object toJava(Object jsObj) {
    if (jsObj instanceof ScriptObjectMirror) {
      var jsObjectMirror = (ScriptObjectMirror) jsObj;
      if (jsObjectMirror.isArray()) {
        var list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : jsObjectMirror.entrySet()) {
          list.add(toJava(entry.getValue()));
        }
        return list;
      } else {
        var map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : jsObjectMirror.entrySet()) {
          map.put(entry.getKey(), toJava(entry.getValue()));
        }
        return map;
      }
    } else {
      return jsObj;
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws ScriptException, NoSuchMethodException {
    var code = String.join("\n",
"function objProvider() {",
"  return {a:1, b:'2','c': true,'d': {'e':[],'f':['1',{'g':45}]}}",
"}",
"function toJavascript (jObj) {",
"  if (jObj instanceof java.util.List) {",
"    var l = []; for each (var item in jObj) {",
"      l.push(toJavascript(item));",
"    }",
"    return l;",
"  }",
"  if (jObj instanceof java.util.Map) {",
"    var m = {}; for each (var key in jObj.keySet()) {",
"      m[key] = toJavascript(jObj.get(key));",
"    }",
"    return m;",
"  }",
"  return jObj;",
"}"
);
    var engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");
    engine.eval(code);
    var jsObj = ((Invocable) engine).invokeFunction("objProvider");
    var formatted = ((Invocable) engine).invokeMethod(engine.eval("JSON"), "stringify", jsObj);
    System.out.println("JSON.stringify(jsObj): " + formatted);
    var javaObj = toJava(jsObj);
    System.out.println("javaObj: " + javaObj);
    //{a=1, b=2, c=true, d={e=[], f=[1, {g=45}]}}
    var newJsObj = ((Invocable) engine).invokeFunction("toJavascript", javaObj);
    formatted = ((Invocable) engine).invokeMethod(engine.eval("JSON"), "stringify", newJsObj);
    System.out.println("JSON.stringify(newJsObj): " + formatted);
    // just to show this doesn't work without conversion
    formatted = ((Invocable) engine).invokeMethod(engine.eval("JSON"), "stringify", javaObj);
    System.out.println("JSON.stringify(javaObj):  " + formatted);
  }
}
```